# How to make is so the site logo can be changed easily without using the customizer?

Tags: logo

I am working on my first wordpress site for quite a while. I'm building a site for someone who doesn't want to use the customizer, so this has been removed. You use to be able to click on apperance>header and not get directed to the customizer? You could change the site logo on a header page in the admin area.

Please can someone suggest a solution, for someone who doesn't want to use the customizer to change their site logo? It must involve no coding for the site admin.

Thanks!

Comment: not quite sure what you're are asking here.. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since going forward all themes in the theme repository will have to use the customizer for everything https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2015/04/21/this-weeks-meeting-important-information-regarding-theme-options/, I would expect any other functionality that have done similar things to be deprecated from core with time.

If you want different image upload functionality then best thing is probably to write your own and not to rely on the core to supply working GUI for it.